# What graph is denoted by I_t?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading a paper (found here [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/combinatorics-probability-and-computing/article/improper-colouring-of-graphs-with-no-odd-clique-minor/F0C6091DDB46096417FFDAF60FCEC87C)) and a type of graph is denoted as $I_t$. What kind of graph is meant by this?

Comment: You should know that your reference is behind a paywall. Therefore, you must include in your question a significant part of the paper where $I_t$ is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else I now found out that they mean a graph with $t$ vertices and no edges by this.

Comment: No it is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact defined in the paper. Midway through the third page, we've got:

> What happens if the forbidden graph $H$ is not complete? **Let $I_t$ be a graph on $t$ vertices with no edges**, and for graphs $G$ and $H$, let $G + H$ be a graph obtained from the disjoint union of $G$ and $H$ by adding an edge between each vertex of $G$ and each vertex of $H$. For positive integers $s$ and $t$, let $K^∗_{s,t}$ be a graph obtained from $K_s + I_t$ by subdividing every edge joining vertices of the subgraph $K_s$ once.

In general, you should expect notation that's not completely standard to be defined somewhere early on in the paper!